# Ms Access Hide and Show Fields based on combo box choice

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have a Userform in Access. In my Userform I have a ComboBox with 3 option: A, B and C. Based on there values, I would like to hide/unhide Text boxes. This is the scenario:

When i select A i want to automatically do the following. 
* Show text box 1
* Hide text box 2

When B 
* Hide textbox 1
* Show textbox 2

When C
* Show textbox 1
* Show textbox 2

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to make use of the After Update event of the ComboBox, which will say the logic of what needs to be done when. Something like,

```
Private Sub comboBoxName_AfterUpdate()
    Select Case Me.comboBoxName
        Case "A"
            Me.textBox1Name.Visible = True
            Me.textBox2Name.Visible = False
        Case "B"
            Me.textBox1Name.Visible = False
            Me.textBox2Name.Visible = True
        Case Else
        'Case "C" is also valid
            Me.textBox1Name.Visible = True
            Me.textBox2Name.Visible = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks PaulFrancis.Its a great contribution from your side in my learning.I must say thanks once again.